# xml serialiser with lists and other objects

Tags: c#, xml

I've been looking here for a sollution, but I did not find it in previous answers.
I need to create the following xml with the serialiser

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>
<documents xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <document>
    <Keys>
      <drawer>GraphicData</drawer>
      <somedata>otherData</somedata>
    </Keys>
    <otherGenericProperties>
      <Data>GenericData 2</Data>
    </otherGenericProperties>
    <Repeat>
          <FileInfo mimeType="application/pdf" HREF="PdfFile.pdf" />
    </Repeat>
    <Repeat>
          <FileInfo mimeType="application/pdf" HREF="PdfFile2.pdf" />
      </Repeat>
 </document>
</documents>
```

The data consist of a few classes

```
namespace test
{
    public class Documents
    {
        [XmlElement("Keys")] // this is used so the destination name can change in the future
        public Keys keys { get; set; }
    }


    public class document
    {
        [XmlElement("Keys")] // this is used so the destination name can change in the future
        public Keys keys { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Repeat")]   // This does not work 
        List<Repeat> listRepeat { get; set; }
    }

    public class Keys
    {
        [XmlElement("drawer")]
        public string drawer { get; set; }
    }

    public class Repeat
    {
        [XmlElement("fileInfo")]
        public FileInfo fileInfo { get; set; }
    }

    public class FileInfo
    {
        public string FileInfo { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("mimeType")]
        public string mimeType { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("mimeType")]
        public string HREF { get; set; }
    }
}
```

the serialiser :

```
     XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Documents));
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(saveBestand, false, xmlEncoding))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, icm, namespaces);
    }
```

I really need the xm like the example, and also the xml names should be changable by a contract like xmlElement is used for. Somehow the repeat element cant be placed on the level you see in the example. Does anyone have a sollution ?

Comment: Your class structure doesn't seem to reflect the XML. For example, your outer element is `documents` with a child of `document` but in your class structure it has a child of `Keys`. The XmlSerializer is never going to even see a repeat class in your example. Also, your `listRepeat` is not marked as public so won't be seen by the XmlSerializer even if that class were present.

Answer (score 0):

you have two options.

**Option 1**
use xsd.exe to generate classes using the xml you want.

```
xsd yourxmlfile.xml
xsd yourxmlfile.xsd /classes
```

This will generate classes which you can use for serialization or deserialization.

**Option 2:**
Paste special option to generate the c# classes. 
This does not involve using the command line.

refer blog at: https://dennymichael.net/2014/05/30/convert-xml-to-csharp-classes/comment-page-1/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you poorly designed your data classes. Try solution below.

```
public class OtherGenericProperties
{
    [XmlElement("Data")]
    public string Data { get; set; }
}
[XmlRoot("documents")]
public class Documents
{
    [XmlElement("document")]
    public Document Document { get; set; }
}
public class Document 
{
    [XmlElement("Keys")] // this is used so the destination name can change in the future
    public Keys Keys { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("otherGenericProperties")]
    public OtherGenericProperties OtherGenericProperties { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Repeat")]   // This does not work 
    public List<Repeat> ListRepeat { get; set; }
}
public class Keys
{
    [XmlElement("drawer")]
    public string Drawer { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("somedata")]
    public string SomeData { get; set; }
}
public class Repeat
{
    [XmlElement("FileInfo")]
    public FileInfo FileInfo { get; set; }
}
public class FileInfo
{
    [XmlAttribute("mimeType")]
    public string MimeType { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("HREF")]
    public string Href { get; set; }
}
```

Serializing:

```
   internal static void Test()
    {
        var doc = new Documents
        {
            Document = new Document
            {
                Keys = new Keys
                {
                    Drawer = "GraphicData",
                    SomeData = "otherData"
                },
                OtherGenericProperties = new OtherGenericProperties { Data = "GenericData 2" },
                ListRepeat = new List<Repeat>
                {
                    new Repeat { FileInfo =new FileInfo { Href = "PdfFile.pdf", MimeType = "application/pdf" } },
                    new Repeat { FileInfo = new FileInfo { Href = "PdfFile2.pdf", MimeType = "application/pdf" } }
                }
            }
        };

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Documents));
        using (var f = new StreamWriter("D:\\doc.xml", false, Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252")))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(f, doc);
            f.Flush();
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>
<documents xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <document>
    <Keys>
      <drawer>GraphicData</drawer>
      <somedata>otherData</somedata>
    </Keys>
    <otherGenericProperties>
      <Data>GenericData 2</Data>
    </otherGenericProperties>
    <Repeat>
      <FileInfo mimeType="application/pdf" HREF="PdfFile.pdf" />
    </Repeat>
    <Repeat>
      <FileInfo mimeType="application/pdf" HREF="PdfFile2.pdf" />
    </Repeat>
  </document>
</documents>
```

Comment: Hello,

Thanks for the answers, it is exactly what I needed, I also see where I went wrong.

Best Regards,